# How to count the number of characters in a line, not from file?

Tags: python-3.x

this my 5th day of learning programming in python. Now I looking solution to print a line which will be long as inputted by user text. For simple program is easy. The three hours of manipulating python commands gave me that what I wanted.

```
print('Write any word:')
inputted_word = input()
print("-" * int(len(inputted_word)))
print("Your word has got: ",len(inputted_word), "characters.")
```

Screen:

```
Write any word:
python
------
Your word has got:  6 characters.
```

*Yes, for me is better to find a solution by myself rather than get it from the web.*
However, I would like to make a table (in this case multiplication tables). A user should be input a multiplication number. Ok, this is done.

```
print('Write any number:')
d = input()
for i in range(1, int(d)+1):
    print(i, end=' ')
    for j in range(1,11):
       print(j, end=' ')
    print()
```

Screen (don't worries about the same numbers):

```
Write any number:
4
1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
3 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
4 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

But how to count the number of characters in 1st line to achieve exactly number to create a line? I presume we need to go out from the loop. So, how to make this? As well as how to make vertical line divided the first column? Any tips, solution for the beginner user, who spent the whole day to reading python documentation and info from the web?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break things up into functions. We want the main part of our program to look like this:

```
word = get_word()  # e.g. "python"

print_table(len(word))  # makes table of 6 characters
```

So let's write our functions. The first one is exactly what you wrote:

```
def get_word():
    print('Write any word:')
    word = input()
    print("-" * int(len(word)))
    print("Your word has got: ", len(word), " characters.")

    return word
```

For the second function, we can do it similar to your way:

```
def print_table(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(i, end=' ')
        print('|', end=' ')     # vertical column
        for j in range(1, 11):
           print(j, end=' ')
        print()
```

The way I'd do it personally is using something called a "list comprehension" and the `str.join()` function to make each row first:

```
def print_table(n):
    # Make a string containing '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10'
    row = ' '.join(str(x) for x in range(1, 11))

    # Print n rows
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        print(str(i) + ' | ' + row)
```